# Problems with MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor) simulation in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, over-voltage-protection, varistor, mov

I recently ask a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669556/ltspice-error-with-varistor-model-and-impulse-current-test/669560?noredirect=1#comment1784644_669560) relating this topic because I was having problems with the spice models supplied by the manufacturers wich consists of a logarithmic power law:

[image]

The problem was of the type "Time step too small".

Since then @Tim Williams suggested me to use a table expresion to attemt to solve the problem but the same problem arised:

```
.SUBCKT SIOV 1 2 PARAMS: T=1 C=1pF L=1nH B1=1 B2=1 B3=0 B4=0
R_SERIES  1 3 100u
L_SERIES  3 4 {L}
V_I_SENSE 4 5 0V
H_I_SENSE 6 0 V_I_SENSE 10k
R_I_SENSE 6 0 1G
B_VAR     5 2 table = (1e-6,799.968) (1e-5,927.732) (1e-4,1019.74) (1e-3,1099.143) (1e-2,1176.691) (1e-1,1257.9) (1,1347.942) (1e1,1457.19) (1e2,1614.786) (1e3,1914.646) (1e4,2728.713) 
C_PAR    4 2 {C}
B_SW 7 0 VALUE={PWR(10,(B1+B2*(-7)+B3*EXP(+7)+B4*EXP(-7)))}
R_SW 7 0 1G 
.ENDS
```

After that I wanted to find a better analytical function to substitute the logarithmic model and found this:

[image] [image]

The yellow curve is  the TDK varistor model with the following parameters:

```
B1=2.9094171 B2=0.0246895 B3=-0.0001545 B4=0.0052839
```

The blue curve is my custom function, whose parameters are the following:

```
K1=840 K2=1 K3=-0.5  a1=0.03 a2=0.735 a3=-0.344
```

The subcircuit netlis is the following:

```
.SUBCKT MOV_model 1 2 PARAMS: C=1pF L=1nH K1=840 K2=1 K3=-0.5  a1=0.03 a2=0.735 a3=-0.344
R_SERIES  1 3 100u
L_SERIES  3 4 20n
V_I_SENSE 4 5 0V
H_I_SENSE 6 0 V_I_SENSE 10k
R_I_SENSE 6 0 1G
B_VAR     5 2  V={ K1*LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G)**a1 + K2*LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G)**a2 + K3*LIMIT(V(6),1m,100G)**a3}
.ENDS
```

The problem that I have now is that its no behaving as expected. For example, when connecting the varistor to an RLC circuit (used to produce impulse currents as 8/20 waveform) usually the internal resistance, inductance and capacitance of the varistor are negligible to the RLC values of the RLC circuit and it should look like this:

[image]

[image]

But instead, the presence of the varistor with this model does change the circuit dynamics significantly:

[image]

Basically, I suspect there is something wrong with the way I'm writing the subcircuit expresion. But I havent find the issue yet and maybe there is something else that I am missing. Any idea?

Edit1: Some of you suggested a better description of the circuit that I'm using. Here is a more detailed screnshoot :

[image]

Following @tobalt suggestion I tried using the following formula for the variable resistance:

[image: formula]

This variable resistance aproach actually works better although it still not producing the expected results since the short circtuit current still difers from the current across the varistor

[image]

The blue curve is  the varistor modeled as a variable resistance, the red curve is with my MOV model based on a behavioral voltage source. What changes should I make to model the negative part of the impulse?

Edit 2: After fidgeting around I noticed that in my subcircuit model (and also de TDK model) the "H_SENSE" line has a transconductance of 10k which I dont understand why they chose this value instead of just 1 since "H_SENSE" is transforming the measured current from "V_SENSE" to a voltage in order to use it in the formula as @SteKulov mentioned in a coment.

For now, it seems that with these changes my model is working a little bit better

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer. Of course, if you don't like those edits you can roll-back to your version.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy!

Comment: could you post a spice schematic of you varistor model? are you sure that the component names work as they should with the underscore?

Comment: it looks like you have a voltage source `BV` there? I guess it is better to simply use a resistor that directly depends on the voltage between nodes 1 and 2. and then some Cpar and Lser

Comment: Do you mean the  underscore in the "MOV_model" name? If yes, I'm pretty positive its this syntax is okay since I have already used it for other models before.  :)

Comment: I meant the components *inside* the model like R_SERIES...

Comment: @tobalt, isn't the variable resistor model based on behavioral voltage/current sources? Either way I will try it out in a sec

Comment: Afaik the `R= V(1,2) * ...` description assign an actual linear resistance at each solution time step.

Comment: I gave up on helping with your previous question because you did not provide enough information for someone to duplicate your simulation and therefore your problem and a possible solution.  You're doing the exact same thing here.  Your screenshot is missing the model for the switch and the control voltage (the node called `ctrl`).  It's also missing the `.tran` statement and I'm unsure if you're using some kind of `.ic` statement for the C1.  Why do you always leave out this vital information?

Comment: Hi @SteKulov, my apologies for the missing information and thanks for pointing out. I already modified the question and added another more detailed screnshot.

Comment: I finally got around to redrawing your circuit and testing your custom equation.  I get a much different result if I change the limits in the LIMIT function to `LIMIT(V(6),1u,100k)` which matches the equation in your question \$10^{-6} \leq x \leq 10^{5}\$.  Does that look more correct to you?

Comment: Your syntax for the `table` approach is wrong.  Can you explain what your ordered pairs of data are intended to represent?

Comment: Did you also change the transconducance value? Because thats what made a bigger change for me at least. I also tried what you said and I havent seen any difference...

Comment: About the table, I honestly dont remember where I saw that you could put it like that hahaha Those points are extractred from the TDK expression https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hv30lyzooj?lang=es

Comment: I meant what is the format of the points. Are the points defined as (current,voltage) or (voltage,current) ?

Comment: Oh sorry, they are ordered as (current, voltage)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a voltage **source** in your model, you should use a variable resistor.

You have derived the \$I(V)\$ relationship. So the corresponding resistance description \$R(V) = \frac{V}{I(V)}\$.

Comment: A behavioral resistor in LTspice converts into a behavioral current source with the `I=` set to the voltage across it divided by what `R=` is set to. Regardless, the reason why TDK uses that goofy H-source off to the side is because of the blurb explained in the LTspice help that says: "..the circuit element current is varying quasi-statically, that is, there is no instantaneous feedback between the current through the referenced device and the behavioral source output". The additional H-source converts the current to a voltage which is then used in the behavioral expression without a problem.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks for the insight  Does that mean, that the subckt is actually correct, but some other problem is likely present, albeit undisclosed? In that case, I could delete this answer

Comment: No problem.  Hmmm...I'm not sure.  The questioner has not posted enough information for anyone else to duplicate their issue exactly and therefore test out a solution.  They did the same thing with the previous question they referenced.  I asked for clarification.  So let's just wait it out for now???

Comment: Why is it more convenient to use a variable resistor instead of a variable voltage source?